# How to test an '&attr' from directive with isolated scope using karma?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test an directive's callback function

To be short (angular 1.x, karma and angular-mocks):

The directive points:

- $scope.show is a function
- $scope.show expected "message" parameter

The directive code:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('alertCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.show({
        message: 'Hello'
    })
})
.directive('alert', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'alertCtrl',
        scope: {
            show: '&'
        }
    }
})
```

The spec:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  $scope.show = function (message) {
    alert(message)
  }
})

it('must execute an expression', function(){
  element = $compile(`
    <alert show="show(message)"></alert>`)($scope);

  $scope.$digest() // It makes no difference
  scope = element.isolateScope()
  scope.$digest() // It makes no difference
  console.log(angular.mock.dump(scope)) // scope.show == undefined
})
```

After compile is complete the directive property "show" is undefined. I miss something?

**EDIT:**

The full code ...

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('alertCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.show({
        message: 'Hello'
    })
})
.directive('alert', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'alertCtrl',
        scope: {
            show: '&',
            bind: '=',
            string: '@'
        }
    }
})

describe('test', function(){

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('test'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
  }))

  beforeEach(function () {
    $scope.show = function (message) {
      alert(message)
    }
    $scope.bind = {data: 123}
  })

  it('must execute an expression', function(){
    element = $compile(`
      <alert show="show(message)"
        bind="bind"
        string="'World'"
        ></alert>`)($scope);

    $scope.$digest() // It makes no difference
    scope = element.isolateScope()
    scope.$digest() // It makes no difference
    console.log(angular.mock.dump(scope)) // scope.show == undefined
  })

})
```

The output of karma...
    ALERT: 'Hello'
    LOG: '  Scope(3): {
        show: undefined
        bind: {"data":123}
        string: "'World'"
    }'
    Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.01 secs / 0.036 secs)

Comment: I believe what you did is right, only the testing part looks wrong. 
try replace 

     `$scope.$digest() // It makes no difference
     scope = element.isolateScope()
     scope.$digest() // It makes no difference
     console.log(angular.mock.dump(scope)) // scope.show == undefined`

by 

     `$scope.$digest();
     expect(element.isolateScope().show).toBeDefined();`

I advised you to use a `spy` to test function binding instead.

Comment: Jasmine' spyOn function worked great! Thanks @JulonLou!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you declare the show function in the wrong shared scope var. Did you declare the scope var right under your declare statement and init it in a beforeeach with a $rootScope.$new() then add your function to it then pass it to your directive instanciation?